# Selecting list items that are not links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to convert user entered unordered lists in a content management system into a bootstrap menu (navbar) using jquery.

80% there apart from one challenge that I can't figure out a nice solution for - ie one that uses selectors rather than string manipulation or regex. After all, we all know that we never parse html with regex :)

So, using the limited UI tools at the user's disposal, they generate a list, usually a two level nested list something like this

```
<ul>
 <li>Blah1
  <ul>
   <li><a href='http://xxxx'>Blah1a</a></li>
   <li><a href='http://yyyy'>Blah1b</a></li>
   <li>Blah1c</li>
   <li><a href='http://zzzz'>Blah1d</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href='http://aaaa'>Blah2</a></li>
 <li>Blah3
  <ul>
   <li><a href='http://xxxx'>Blah2a</a></li>
   <li><a href='http://yyyy'>Blah2b</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

And so on... The important thing is that some of their list items are links, some are just text.

I need to select each block of text contained in an <li> that is not already wrapped in an <a> and wrap it in an <a href="#"> so that the above would be transformed into:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href='#'>Blah1</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href='http://xxxx'>Blah1a</a></li>
   <li><a href='http://yyyy'>Blah1b</a></li>
   <li><a href='#'>Blah1c</a></li>
   <li><a href='http://zzzz'>Blah1d</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href='http://aaaa'>Blah2</a></li>
 <li><a href='#'>Blah3</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href='http://xxxx'>Blah2a</a></li>
   <li><a href='http://yyyy'>Blah2b</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li> 
</ul>
```

Shouldn't be that difficult I'm sure, but after an hour of playing I'm getting nowhere.

Comment: After the bit of tongue-in-cheek about never using regex to parse HTML I am left wondering whether you have tried it for this problem and if not, why not?  How about a selection across all "li" elements and iterating through the children to see if there is a direct "a" element descendant (slow, but easy to check for correctness).

Comment: Indeed I probably could - but I think my soul would be damned for all of eternity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I actually have a t-shirt of that classic StackOverflow answer - how sad is that?

Comment: I am very sad that it is a closed post and I can't up vote the Chuck Norris can parse HTML with regex comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$('li').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0
}).wrap('<a href="#" />')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UgcqW/)

Comment: Deleting mine, yours is better

Comment: You should use `Node.TEXT_NODE` rather than just  3; it's more descriptive of what you're doing.

Comment: Like that - short, elegant and working in my test examples. Thanks +1 now and accepted later (just in case someone aces it)

Comment: What's wrong with my answer?  Uses jQuery selectors and should perform faster.

Comment: Not sure what's happening - have a look at the generated html on your fiddle - you'll see it has created a number of empty a's. Look after each sub-list for an example

Comment: Two great answers - difficult to pick between them so I'm taking some advice from a discussion over on Meta and going for the one that suits me the best. This one works consistently across all of my existing test cases and will be easiest to adapt when users come up with a new variation. As this is what I'll be using, both get +1's but this is the one that gets the tick.

Answer (score 3):

One line of code here:

```
$("li").not(":has(>a)").wrapInner('<a href="#" />');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnmn5/2/)

So, if you want to just get the text nodes than, yeah, use `.contents()`, which will get all nodes, including text nodes.  Here are 2 methods you can use below for this:

```
$("li").not(":has(>a)").contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()).length > 0
}).wrap('<a href="#" />');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnmn5/3/)

And here is another approach, just for the sake of something different:

```
$("li").not(":has(>a)").each(function(){
      var $contents = $(this).contents();
      if ($contents.length)
          $contents.eq(0).wrap('<a href="#" />');
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnmn5/5/)

Comment: Works fine for me.  You should test this on a live server, if you are looking at jsFiddle, I've come to realize that jsFiddle sometimes has a problem loading up the jQuery libraries on certain browsers.  Try testing by changing the jQuery library to 2.0, or any from 1.6 on.

Comment: Updated answer, I see what the problem was.  Works perfectly fine now!

Comment: Still not quite... Look at blah1 on your fiddle the text and the entire ul child are all wrapped in the a

Comment: If you only want text within the `li` elements wrapped, than use Arun P Johny answer, but if the li elements could contain `html` elements within it, than use my approach to wrap them.  It's up to how you choose to use it.  And there's nothing wrong with the `<a>` tag wrapping the `<ul>` within it, it doesn't overwrite the URLs that are on the other `<li>` tags within that `<ul>`  Soo, it all comes down to exactly what you want wrapped within an `<a>` tag I suppose.

Comment: There are now 3 different answers that I added here with jsfiddles for each.  Take your pick!